# how to get up row in wordpress with wpdb

Tags: plugin-development

I want to compare two prices in my database. I get a row with any id:

```
$price1 = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prices WHERE id = 10" );
```

I want to get up the row from this table means I want to get row same bellow but if row by id 9 is deleted it's missing:

```
$price1 = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prices WHERE id = 9" );
```

How do this?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I have a field that common between these two rows and handle width **limit** parameter in my query.

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2", $post_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add another field to your `prices` table called `previous_id` and keep it updated on every insert and delete query.

This way you may always have the track for previous record. If you deletethat record, you may assign its `previous_id` into the next record and if you insert new record, you may add the last available id into its `previous_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get row by **`id = 10`** if it is deleted then checks for **`id = 9`** and so on.

```
$price1 = '';
for($id = 10; $price1==''; $id--){
    $price1 = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = $id" );
}
```

If **`id = 10`** is present, it will be selected directly. Loop will run only once.

If you want to get next row (i.e.11th) simply replace **`$id--`** with **`$id++`**